# 'Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1' when try to install ssdeep

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-3.4

when i try to install ssdeep

```
pip install ssdeep
```

i get this output message

```
    c:\Python34\Scripts>pip install ssdeep
Collecting ssdeep
  Using cached ssdeep-3.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py
egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\czosnek\
AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mmy6xmrp\ssdeep\
```

I use Windows 7 64 and Python 3.4.

Comment: have you setup pip to target Python3 ? otherwise try `pip3 install ssdeep`

Comment: 'pip3 install ssdeep' gives the same effect ;/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error once when trying to install a package. Try installing the wheel first and then doing it again.

Comment: You mean "pip install wheel"? I just installed it but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

do the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libffi-dev python python-dev pip libfuzzy-dev
```

after just use `pip`:

```
pip install ssdeep
```